# How to setMapToolbarEnabled on ionic 2 google maps native

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to disable the toolbar on android but am receiving setMapToolbarEnabled does not exist on type GoogleMap.

```
this.map.setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

is there another way to do this?  I tried this too, and it didn't work.

```
 this.map = this.googleMaps.create(element, {
  'backgroundColor': 'white',
  'controls': {
    'compass': false,
    'mapToolbar':false
  },
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

it works just dont forget to add api in the app.moel.ts in the proovider also 
https://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-native-google-maps-into-an-ionic-2-application/

Comment: My map is working just fine.. I just want to get rid of the auto directions label in the bottom right.  That is mapped to mapToolbar.  But the link you provided doesn't say a think about mapToolbar.  And you didn't mention which provider to add?  I have GoogleMaps provider included already.